# search for a specific value name and its associated datakey in the registry with powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to search any value name in the registry (HKLM:\Cluster\Resources) that match = VirtualServerName. and output his associated datakey to an array.

For Example:

```
      Name            Type     Data
VirtualServerName    REG_SZ   SQLDEP05
```

But i couldn't find the right switch for a recurring search with the Get-ItemProperty command.

so ive tried using the Get-ChileItem insted:

```
$Reg = "HKLM:\Cluster\Resources\"
Get-ChildItem -recurse "$Reg" | Select-Object -Property VirtualServerName -ExcludeProperty $exclude | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value }
```

Which works only when im using the **.Name** option in the $_.PSObject.Properties switch.

But when i'm trying to get the value of VirtualServerName, **.Value**:

```
$Reg = "HKLM:\Cluster\Resources\"
Get-ChildItem -recurse "$Reg" | Select-Object -Property VirtualServerName -ExcludeProperty $exclude | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value }
```

i don't get any output.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where-Object` to test if a value name exists under a specific key with the [`GetValueNames()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames):

```
$Keys = Get-ChildItem -Path $Reg -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.GetValueNames() -contains 'VirtualServerName'}
```

Now that you've got the relevant key(s), you can grab the value data with `Get-ItemProperty`:

```
$Keys |Get-ItemProperty VirtualServerName
```

or the [`GetValue()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue):

```
$Keys |ForEach-Object {
  $_.GetValue('VirtualServerName')
}
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. but is there a way to filter the output so i will get only the value themselves? meaning only the value of VirtualServerName  and InstanceName.. cause currently i'm getting a lot of unrelated data in the output